# codenameone server build error

Tags: android, codenameone

I am designing an android application using codenameone. after running the application on the codenameone simulator I decided to build, the build server is giving me the following error log :

```
Executing: /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/android create project --target android-21 --name Application --path /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application --activity ApplicationStub --package com.microserve.mssn Created directory /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/src/com/microserve/mssn
Added file /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/src/com/microserve/mssn/ApplicationStub.java
Created directory /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/res
Created directory /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/bin
Created directory /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/libs
Created directory /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/res/values
Added file /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/res/values/strings.xml
Created directory /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/res/layout
Added file /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/res/layout/main.xml
Created directory /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/res/drawable-xhdpi
Created directory /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/res/drawable-hdpi
Created directory /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/res/drawable-mdpi
Created directory /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/res/drawable-ldpi
Added file /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/AndroidManifest.xml
Added file /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/build.xml
Added file /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/proguard-project.txt
Executing: /home/ec2-user/android/ant/bin/ant release Buildfile: /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-release-mode:

-release-obfuscation-check:
     [echo] proguard.config is proguard.cfg
     [echo] Proguard.config is enabled

-pre-build:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.5
 [checkenv] Installed at /home/ec2-user/android-sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: Application
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 20.0.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for Application...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 5.0
[gettarget] API level:        21
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/bin/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/bin/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/bin/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/bin/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/bin/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for Application...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'release'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [aapt] /tmp/build2045678520977010415xxx/Application/res/values/strings.xml:3: error: Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in Da'awah Week)

BUILD FAILED
/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 1

Total time: 1 second
```

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion of the ' character in the app title seems to be the source of the problem. Its something that we can probably fix in the build server but you might have issues with it in other platforms too.